# Can we execute Wokflows that are build on jBPM V6.4 on RHPAM V7.0?

Tags: jbpm

I have build workflows using JBPM V6.4 and its related packages. But when i am trying to execute on the JBOSS server where RHPAM V7.0 is installed, I am getting following error message:-
ERROR [stderr] (default task-15) org.kie.services.client.serialization.SerializationException: Unsupported JAXB Class encountered during initialization.

Is it a problem with JBPM V6.4 installed on the environment where RHPAm V7.0 is running?

Deployed JBPM V6.4 project  on RHPAM V7.0.
Need a confirmation on compatibility.